# Why do i get "multiple applicable items in scope" if type set in the left side?

Tags: rust

Example code:

```rust
struct Test<T>(T);

impl Test<(i32, i32)> {
    fn new(a: i32, b: i32) -> Self {
        Self((a, b))
    }
}

impl Test<(i32, i32, i32)> {
    fn new(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) -> Self {
        Self((a, b, c))
    }
}
```

This code work fine:

```rust
_ = Test::<(_, _)>::new(1, 2);
```

But why doesn't this work?

```rust
// multiple applicable items in scope
let _: Test<(_, _)> = Test::new(1, 2);
```

if the answer is complicated, I would also like to know why these restrictions were added, and why I can't just write:

```rust
_ = Test::new(1, 2);
```

Comment: The answer from @kmdreko is correct. I want to make a slight adjustment to it.
It is worth examining an explanation for the error here(https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0034.html). That's what the compiler tells us while compiling this code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test::new` is ambiguous.

Rust does not support *function overloading*. What you've done here by using the same method name on distinct `impl` blocks can get a similar effect, but it is not the same thing. You should think of these as functions with the same name but in different namespaces: `Test::<(i32, i32)>` and `Test::<(i32, i32, i32)>`.

Rust instead has a strong *type inference* mechanism. This distinction is important in this case because while type inference can "see through" generic functions, it needs to be resolved to a single declaration before it can do its job. Without a function overload resolution mechanism (being able to deduce what overload should be used based on parameters), the Rust compiler finds two candidates for `Test::new` and throws an error requiring *you* to disambiguate them.

```
_ = Test::<(_, _)>::new(1, 2);
```

So in this case, the function is disambiguated (at least well enough) using the fully-qualified syntax which means that `Test::<(i32, i32, i32)>` is not a candidate. Thus a single definition can be resolved. If there were, for example, a `Test::<(f64, f64)>::new` definition as well, it would still be ambigiuous and would need further qualification.

```
let _: Test<(_, _)> = Test::new(1, 2);
```

This doesn't work because, while the type annotation and parameters heavily imply a particular definition, the left side can only make an impact via reverse type inference if it knows the function declaration of what it will infer into and the compiler does not consider the parameters when resolving function.

```
_ = Test::new(1, 2);
```

Same as above.

---

For those reasons, using the same function name for distinct impl blocks is usually relegated to *methods* (where there is a `self` parameter) so that part of the resolution is (usually) already done. See the methods on [`std::any::Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) for example.

---

Why not support function overloading?

1. Overload resolution rules are always complicated by interactions between type coersions and often with ranking systems for choosing the best candidate.
2. It doesn't play well with type inference. Its possible that argument-count overloading (as you've presented in your question) could be made workable, but that wouldn't be a strong enough motivator for supporting it in the language.
3. Rust can achieve function-overloading-like capabilities through type inference and traits. Uses of `From::from` and `Default::default` are common.

See also:

- [Abstraction without overhead: traits in Rust](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/05/11/traits.html) - "overloading" sub-section
- [Why Rust doesn't have function overloading?](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-rust-doesnt-have-function-overloading/80416) from the Rust User's Forum.
- [Why doesn't Rust support overloading function or method?](/q/56508697/2189130)